# mapping multiple clickable elements on top of image at specific locations

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework, button

I am attempting to create a custom world map using an image where you can click on a button that is over a "continent". This is an ionic app and is expected to be launched on both mobile and desktop. The only real answer i can find to fixing this problem is using CSS with `position: absolute;` and then setting the pixels (ex: `top: 50px; left: 30px;`). I am worried that the buttons will not stay in the correct position when it is viewed on different web browsers and when used via a mobile device. Is there a way that i can make sure that the buttons stay in the desired position no matter what, or is the only way to do it is through CSS positioning and px manipulation? attached is the photo of the world map (some parts cut out: https://i.stack.imgur.com/miR28.jpg ) i am trying to implement this on. I want to have a clickable element on top of each continent and centered. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can place a div over the picture and use percentages over pixels but it will still need to be adjusted with @media-queries.